# importing sql into postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

In pgadmin, I selected a table from my production database I want to export. I right clicked and selected backup. I set the filename to devices.sql and selected plain as format. Then I clicked the backup button and it created a sql file on my computer. Now I want to import the contents of that table into my development database. So I run the psql utility and enter the following:

```
\i /Users/GuardDog/Documents/devices.sql
```

But it gives me this error:

```
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
SET
psql:/Users/GuardDog/Documents/devices.sql:34: ERROR:  relation "devices" already exists
psql:/Users/GuardDog/Documents/devices.sql:37: ERROR:  role "xtremek" does not exist
psql:/Users/GuardDog/Documents/devices.sql:50: ERROR:  relation "devices_id_seq" already exists
psql:/Users/GuardDog/Documents/devices.sql:53: ERROR:  role "xtremek" does not exist
ALTER SEQUENCE
 setval 
--------
      2
(1 row)

ALTER TABLE
psql:/Users/GuardDog/Documents/devices.sql:101: ERROR:  multiple primary keys for table "devices" are not allowed
```

I get quite a few errors here. How can I import the data from my production server to development server in pgadmin/PostgreSQL 9.1.2 ?

Comment: Either do a data-only dump on the origin server, or use "custom" format and restore just the data with the `pg_restore` command on the destination server.

Comment: @CraigRinger And how do I do data only dump? Thats what I thought I was doing. I followed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257132/export-postgresql-table-data-using-pgadmin

Comment: You want the `--data-only` option to `pg_dump`. Unsure how to get that from PgAdmin, as I don't use it much. What I'd do personally is either use `psql`'s `\copy` command to copy the table contents to a CSV file, or use PgAdmin-III's Export option (a right click option on a table) to do the same. Then import with psql's `\copy tablename from ...` command.

Comment: Look around the various options [here](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.18/backup.html).

Comment: @CraigRinger I see no "export" option on a pgadmin table

Comment: @JohnMerlino Only recent versions IIRC. http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/export.html